# Printing double in DTrace script for user application defined probe

Tags: c, macos, dtrace

I'm trying to print a double argument in a DTrace script from a [user defined probe](http://dtrace.org/guide/chp-usdt.html). The probe is defined as such:

```
/**
 * Fired when the garbage collection threshold is changed with a certain factor
 * @param factor the factor with which the GC threshold is changed
 */
probe gc__threshold(double factor);
```

In my script I'm trying to print the argument as follows:

```
pony$target:::gc-threshold
{
    print(args[0]);
}
```

However it gives me the following error:

```
dtrace: failed to compile script ./test.d: line 7: translator for args[0] from double to double is not defined
```

I'm running the script on a Mac. Due to the lack of documentation and no similar problem around on the internet I'm having trouble finding leads on how to solve this problem.

*I've also tried using floats and long doubles, but the same error occurs.*